# Resize text items in ggarrange plot panel, plots made with ggpubr

Tags: r, plot, ggpubr

I am creating a multi panel plot with `ggarrange`.
Individual plots are made with `ggpubr::ggbarplot` and the sizing of all the elements in these plots are as I want them:

```
met = ggbarplot(data= month_sum, x= "Month", y = "MET minutes per week",
          fill = "blue4", color = "white") 
met
```

[image]

but when I combine in a single panel the axes text and labels are not the same proportion as the original plots:

```
expanel = ggarrange(res, load, ae_ses, ae_min, met, hr_mon,
          labels = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
          ncol = 2, nrow =  3)
expanel
```

[image]

Is there a single command I can include in `ggarange` toadjust the size of axes text and labels?

Comment: Plots in R have exactly the text size that you specify when you are building the plot. The text size does not change when you increase or decrease the plot size. This means that when your plots are made smaller, either by being drawn on a smaller plotting device, or being drawn as a sub-panel of a multi-panel plot, the text will be proportionately larger. This is a feature, not a bug, though it does take some getting used to. You should use the `size` argument inside `ggbarplot` to change the text size to half its current value to preserve the relative text size.